# BUG: Tensorflow accuracy on training data different when training than when evaluating

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I think I have made some sort of error because my model has a substantially different accuracy while training:

```
Epoch 25/2000
19/19 [==============================] - 26s 1s/step - loss: 2.0174 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4253
```

than when it is evaluated:

```
>>> model3.evaluate(train_dataset)

19/19 [==============================] - 4s 188ms/step - loss: 2.3323 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2987
```

even though these two accuracy scores are being evaluated on the **same data**.

I think there might be something wrong with the batch normalisation layer? Like maybe it's not being applied properly outside of train time? If I look at a confusion matrix for the categorization problem on this data, it is predicting all examples as being from the most probable class.

I'm trying to create the FCN model from Z. Wang, W. Yan and T. Oates, "Time series classification from scratch with deep neural networks: A strong baseline," 2017 International Joint Conference on Neural Networks (IJCNN), Anchorage, AK, USA, 2017, pp. 1578-1585. The model is here:

```py
model3 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=1),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=8, strides=1, padding='same', input_shape=(None, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])

model3.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

Comment: Training's score is of 25th epoch while total epoch is 2K. How many epochs was the model trained?

Comment: Not many so far because I noticed this bug. I'm writing a dissertation with it so I want to have the proper graph of training cost over time, which I can't do if there's a bug in it.

Comment: So you are evaluation your data on the same model with the model at the 25th epoch?